# Swift app lifecycle responding to incoming calls

Tags: ios, swift, lifecycle, audiokit, facetime

I'm working on an AudioKit app, and have run into an issue with managing the app lifecycle. When I receive an incoming FaceTime call, I would like to be able to update my app state so it can recover properly when the call ends and my app is in the foreground again.

When a call is received and the notification appears, my app's audio stops immediately, which is fine.

If the incoming call is accepted, both sceneWillResignActive and sceneDidEnterBackground are called, and I can respond appropriately.

If the incoming call is rejected, or cancelled by the caller before being accepted, even though the audio has stopped, no scene delegates are called, so I am not able to properly update my app state.

I can demonstrate this behaviour by just logging the scene delegate calls in a brand new Swift Storyboard App project. Obviously there is no audio but I can see which delegates are called when a call comes in. And in my testing, if a call is rejected, no delegates are called.

So my question is if there is a way for my app to know about an incoming call, other than the functions in SceneDelegate.

Testing with iPhone 14 Pro / iOS 16.3.1 and iPad Pro (3rd Generation) / iPadOS 16.3.1. I have only tested calling into the device with FaceTime.

To watch the scene delegate calls:

Create a new Swift App Storyboard project, and replace contents of SceneDelegate with the following. Run the app on a physical device, call in to the device from another device using FaceTime, and watch the Xcode debug console. Try accepting and rejecting the FaceTime calls to see the difference.

```
import UIKit
import os

class SceneDelegate: UIResponder, UIWindowSceneDelegate {
    
    let lifecycle = Logger(subsystem: "com.myComany.lifecycletest", category: "lifecycle")

    var window: UIWindow?


    func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) {
        
        lifecycle.log("scene willConnectTo")
        
        guard let _ = (scene as? UIWindowScene) else { return }
    }

    func sceneDidDisconnect(_ scene: UIScene) {
        
        lifecycle.log("sceneDidDisconnect")

    }

    func sceneDidBecomeActive(_ scene: UIScene) {

        lifecycle.log("sceneDidBecomeActive")

    }

    func sceneWillResignActive(_ scene: UIScene) {
 
        lifecycle.log("sceneWillResignActive")

    }

    func sceneWillEnterForeground(_ scene: UIScene) {

        lifecycle.log("sceneWillEnterForeground")

    }

    func sceneDidEnterBackground(_ scene: UIScene) {

        lifecycle.log("sceneDidEnterBackground")

    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Turns out that the answer to my question is yes:

> "Is there a way for my app to know about an incoming call, other than
> the functions in SceneDelegate."

Everything I needed is here - Use the Notification Center to observe and respond to interruptions. The provided sample code works great!

[Responding to Audio Session Interruptions](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfaudio/avaudiosession/responding_to_audio_session_interruptions)